# Differentiate $f \mapsto \int \limits_{f(0)}^{f(1)} f(t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $U=\{f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}): 0<f(0)<1, 0<f(1)<1 \} \subset \mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. Consider a function $F:U \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f \mapsto \int \limits_{f(0)}^{f(1)} f(t) \ dt$. I want to find the derivative of this function.
By definition the derivative at point $f$ (in our case this is a function) is such linear function $L:\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \exists r>0 : (||h||<r, f+h \in U) \Longrightarrow (|F(f+h)-F(f)-L(h)|\leq \varepsilon||h||)$$
When we substitute $F$ by the integral we have:
$$\left|\ \int \limits_{f(0)}^{f(1)} h(t) dt - L(h) \ \right| \leq \varepsilon||h||$$
And here I'm thinking about using something like integration by substitution
and I will have
$$\left|\ \int \limits_{0}^{1} f(h(t))h'(t) dt - L(h) \ \right| \leq \varepsilon||h||,$$
however there is no guarantee that $h$ is differentable.

How to find such $L$?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your expression for $F(f+h) - F(f)$ is wrong.

Comment: @user159517 why? integral is linear

Comment: Consider the limits of the integral in $F(f+h)$.

Comment: @user159517, oh, you're right, thanks!

Comment: It's not hard to prove that if $f(f(0))=f(f(1))=0$, then the derivative is $h\mapsto \int_{f(0)}^{f(1)} h(t) dt$. Otherwise, I don't know how to prove that $\int_{f(1)}^{f(1)+h(1)}f(t) dt - \int_{f(0)}^{f(0)+h(0)}f(t) dt$ is $o(\|h\|)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $f\in U$ and consider $h$ with $\|h\|$ small. Then

$$ F(f+h) = \int_{f(0) + h(0)}^{f(1) + h(1)} (f+h)$$ $$\tag 1 = \int_{f(0)}^{f(1)}(f+h) +\int_{f(1)}^{f(1) + h(1)}(f+h) - \int_{f(0)}^{f(0) + h(0)}(f+h).$$

In $(1)$ we see three integrals, let's call them $I_1,I_2, I_3.$ We have

$$\tag 2 I_1 = F(f) + \int_{f(0)}^{f(1)}h,$$

which is good because we need to see $F(f)$ isolated, and the integral in $(2)$ is linear in $h.$ Continuing,

$$\tag 3 I_2 = \int_{f(1)}^{f(1) + h(1)}f + \int_{f(1)}^{f(1) + h(1)}h.$$

Let's think about $(3):$ As $\|h\| \to 0,$ we expect the first integral to be close to $f(f(1))h(1)$ by the continuity of $f$ at $f(1).$ In fact it will equal that at the expense of a $o(\|h\|)$ term. The second integral in $(3)$ is clearly $o(\|h\|).$ Thus $(3)$ equals $f(f(1))h(1) +o(\|h\|).$ Similarly, $I_3 = f(f(0))h(0) + o(\|h\|).$

Putting everything together gives

$$F(f+h)= F(f) + \int_{f(0)}^{f(1)}h + f(f(1))h(1) - f(f(0))h(0) + o(\|h\|).$$

Thus $DF(f)(h) = \int_{f(0)}^{f(1)}h + f(f(1))h(1) - f(f(0))h(0).$

Thanks to Daniel Fischer for noticing a mistake, now corrected.

Comment: That should be $f(f(1))\cdot h(1)$ and $f(f(0))\cdot h(0)$ respectively.

Comment: @DanielFischer Egads you're right, thank you.

Comment: I've caught myself making the same mistake, so I knew what to look for ;)

Comment: I've figured out that your estimate is wrong. Instead of $h(0)$ you should take its absolute value (it is the length of the interval and we do not have any guarantee that $h(0)$ takes positive value). Although your assertions are very beautiful and very natural.

Comment: @NicholasS  No, we're OK. If $h(0) < 0,$ then by defiition

$$\int_{f(0)}^{f(0) + h(0)}f= -\int_{f(0) + h(0)}^{f(0)} f.$$

Work through that (note the length of the interval is $-h(0)),$ and you'll see it works out.